# Как поменять цветовую схему изображения?

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_MckQnU0mCF8FJ7PoV21nhVvoOeotHGy#scrollTo=owUFbInCHW9W

на этом сайте ИИ создает анимации по описанию. Как изменить цветовую схему чтобы анимация была в неоновых цветах?
здесь идет преобразование цвета, можно сделать ч/б или в оттенках серого. Но не понимаю как объяснить программе что такое неоновый цвет.

```py
def read_image_workaround(path):
    """OpenCV reads images as BGR, Pillow saves them as RGB. Work around
    this incompatibility to avoid colour inversions."""
    im_tmp = cv2.imread(path)
    return cv2.cvtColor(im_tmp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

[image: пример изображения в неоновых цветах]

Comment: какой цвет на вашей фотографии по вашему "неоновый", залейте однотонную картинку с желаемым цветом

Comment: чтобы запустить создание анимации нужно по порядку прожать все значки play слева и дождаться конца загрузки каждой,  занимает минут 5. 
 в параметр text_prompts можно ввести  текстовый запрос на основе которого будет создаваться анимация

Comment: Еще раз, в вашем "вопросе" сказано **Но не понимаю как объяснить программе что такое неоновый цвет.**, вы сами понимаете что такое "неоновый цвет" чтобы объяснить это программе? на первой фотографии я вижу инверсию цветов, и никакого "неонового цвета", что видите вы - мне неизвестно, поэтому если вы хотите объяснить программе что такое неоновый цвет, вам необходимо суметь объяснить это не только лишь себе.

Comment: это анимация, все цвета меняются и инвертируются.  В моем задании сказано сделать неоновую анимацию. То есть, наверное, чтобы цвета были яркими, выкрученными на максимум. Черный кажется не подходит, любой другой цвет, может быть неоновым(очень ярким)

Comment: ИИ сам подбирает цвета. Его надо ограничить чтобы он выбирал только очень яркие цвета для создания анимации.

Comment: Дерзайте, https://arboook.com/kompyuternoe-zrenie/operatsii-s-tsvetom-v-opencv3-i-python/, как только вы поймете что такое "яркость" - вы сможете решить задачу :) ах да, подсказка вы хотите манипуляции которые легко делать в HSV :)

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, нет такой модели как "неоновая". При необходимости вы можете взять свое
изображение и изменять яркости каждого канала так как вам необходимо для получения результата. По какой формуле менять яркости? ну здесь вам никто не подскажет, т.к. неоновый цвет это не очень четкое понятие. Возможно, имеет смысл вообще использовать не RGB модель, а HSV